# allocating and populating a large array

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I want to allocate and initialize a very large array of unsigned long ints. The array is a simple 1-D array, and I want to populate it with the value of the first N primes. I already have a program that will spit these out into a .cpp file for inclusion. I'm just not sure of the syntax to initialize the array. I know that

```
unsigned long int *known = new unsigned long int[N];
```

will create the array on the heap, but I'm not sure how to initialize the members.

Answer (score 2):

You basically just loop over the array and assign the correct value to every element, like so:

```
for(size_t idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx)
{
  *(known + idx) = retrieve_value(idx);
}
```

Obviously with the `retrieve_value` function returning the appropriate value that needs to be assigned to known[idx].

You can also make use of the pointer/array equivalence and write the code using array syntax:

```
for(size_t idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx)
{
  known[idx] = retrieve_value(idx);
}
```

That said, unless there is a good reason for new'ing the array this way I would strongly recommend using one of the standard containers like std::vector or std::array in this case as it'll avoid the memory management headaches that are mostly unnecessary these days. If N is known at compile time, `std::array` is likely to have less overhead, otherwise using `std::vector` with an appropriate reserve() call should do the job fine, too. I would really only suggest dealing with raw memory if you absolutely have to squeeze the last byte out of the available memory.

Comment: So I did some research and took your advice and tried this so that it would be defined on the heap:                               std::vector<int> *known = new vector<int>;

 known[1] = 2; known[2] = 3; known[3] = 5; known[4] = 7;
 known[5] = 11; known[6] = 13; known[7] = 17; known[8] = 19;
 known[9] = 23; known[10] = 29; known[11] = 31; known[12] = 37; j = known[i];                                                       but I still get errors. The declaration works fine, but it doesn't let me populate the members. I'm still learning / relearning a lot of this, so thank you both for your help.

Comment: You don't need to allocate the vector on the heap. The implementation will automatically do that for the storage anyway in most cases. Just use `std::vector<int> known;`. If you want to use the assignments into your vector as you wrote above you also need to call `known.resize(size)` or initialize/size the vector on creation. Have a look at cppreference.com or similar sites for a full description of the vector API.

Comment: OK, I have the syntax right. It works if I paste it directly into my program. If I include the definition in KnownPrimes.h, though I get a compiler error "g++: error: KnownPrimes.o: No such file or directory". Why would the compiler be looking for a .o file?

Comment: Another little tidbit - Eclipse is feeding KnownPrimes.o to the linker.  The question I suppose is why is Eclipse trying to get gcc to link a file it never creates?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create an array initializer class which will accept a pointer to array and number of elements to be created. Use a global variable of this class.
Upon creation the constructor will populate the array.

```
    class ArrayInitializer{
       ArrayInitializer(unsigned long* ptr, size_t Size);
       ...
       ...
    };
```

Now create a global variable

```
    //include your header here,
    ArrayInitializer g_arrayInit(known,N);
```

Global variables are created as soon as program execution begins. Also you can you this class to clean up the memory allocated using 'new'

Comment: I don't quite understand what this would buy the original poster? Especially the global variable part.